# Insert hours and date in MS access via excel vba

Tags: date, ms-access, excel, vba

I'm trying to insert this datas to MS Access via vba excel but I keep getting an error

```
    dates = Cells(4, "E").Value ' contains 9/11/2013 '
    hours= "7:30"
connDB.Execute "INSERT INTO DeptOrder (IDDept, DateIntervention, HourIntervention, bilaterale) VALUES (4,  "& #dates# &" , "&hours&" , true)"
```

This the latest version of my query.  The error message is *"data type mismatch in criteria expression"*.

```
INSERT INTO DeptCommande
(IDDept, IDIntervention, DateIntervention, HeureIntervention, bilatérale, IDChirurgien, NumSalle)
VALUES ('5' , '574', #09-10-2013#, '0.322916666666667', 'True', '1', '4')
```

Comment: Are you inserting numbers/booleans as strings into numeric fields -- `1`, `True`? When inserting numbers or booleans, there is no need for quotation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks HansUp!!! I did remove all unecessay quotes and it's finally working. Sorry for the long query I wanted to post a short question by adding a few variables only.

`VALUES (" & ledept & " , " & lintervention & ", #" & ladate & "#, " & heurevoulue & ", " & bilat & ", " & nomchiru & ", " & numeroSalle & ")"
Debug.Print strInsert`

`VALUES (5 , 574, #10-11-2014#, 0.322916666666667, True, 1, 4)`